# PHP Compare result to high score database returns duplicate values

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery function that send the result time variable to a php file that compares the result to the database and returns 1 if it is a new highscore.. but for some reason it is returning 111

Here is the PHP:

```
require_once('db.php');

$sql = "SELECT score FROM highscores ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$score = $_POST['time'];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['score'] > $score) {
        echo 1;
    }
}
```

and then the jquery function:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'model/highscore.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: {time:totalTime},
    success:function(result){
        highScore = result;
    }
});
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: You are looping through 10 highscores records, maybe it printed three times `1` because it found 3 higher scores?

Comment: Thanks man.. Now I feel like an idiot!!! Let me see if i can fix it quick...

Comment: just add a `break;` after the echo.

Comment: @dawidvanderhoven i added my answer, please check it

Comment: Well luk2302 answered first.. but since i cant mark a comment as the answer.. you are correct Fabio thank you :)

Comment: But the answer is not correct! It could also break if its not the best but the second best score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you modify your SQL Query to your needs?

You are fetching the 10 highest scores, and loop through all of them, to check, how many scores are actually higher than yours. But you actually don't check, if your score is higher than the highest.

If you want to check, if your score is the highest, count all scores that are higher than yours. If there is none (count = 0), you know you got the highest.

Edit: 
Here is the complete script:

```
$score = $_POST['time']; // Format "00:00:02.95";
$sql = "SELECT Count(score) as c FROM highscores WHERE score > '".mysqli_real_escape_string($score)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$count = mysqli_fetch_object($result)->c;
if(!is_null($count) && $count < 1 )
    echo 1;
}
```

Adding the escaping function is mandatory to protect against SQL injection!

You should also find a better data-type for your score, because varchar is not the best respresentation for a timestamp.

I am out now.

Edit: Check if $count is not null

Comment: Hey man, Your method is not working for me, I am not sure if i am implementing it incorrectly but heres what i have:

$score = $_POST['time'];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(score) FROM highscores WHERE score > '".$score."' ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 if(count == 0) {
  echo 1;
  break;
 }
}

Comment: wait a sec, i ll make it for you. Which value has $_POST['time'] and whats the datatype of "score" column?

Comment: $_POST['time'] = 00:00:02.95 and then the datatype is   varchar(255)

Comment: What does that represent? HH:MM:SS.MS? If you store it as varchar in database, you can't use compare functions like > or <? You need a format that is comparable. Do you need millisecond precision?

Comment: I am surprised, the varchar compare works too. Wait a minute, ill write the code for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31319/discussion-between-dawid-van-der-hoven-and-larrydahooster)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the database itself this is mostly a guess, but I'm guessing it's returning 3 separate scores from your database. You need to limit your query to 1.

Comment: limiting the returned data to 1 will take the chance away to check if the score should be in the highscore-list.

Comment: You need to modify your query to be something like `"SELECT score FROM highscores WHERE score > $_POST['score'] ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 1"`

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you are looping through 10 highscores record and it found 3 higher result so it printed three time 1, like it was

```
echo 1;
echo 1;
echo 1;
```

that outputs

```
111
```

You can just put a break after your `echo 1`

```
echo 1;
break;
```

Comment: Because it is not right. It does not indicate that you have the highest score! It could break at 10th best score, returning true

Comment: @larry read question carefully, he's asking why it prints three times

Comment: Yeah, but he wants to return a single 1, if it is a new highscore. So, do we want to stop him from getting more than a single 1, or do we want to help him making things right?

Comment: @larry of course we want to help him get right, but he's comparing database records to input, of course there could be more than one, no other way round.

Comment: @larry I think he doesn't need to see what is the higher score stored in database, he just wants to see if input is higher than all records